# How can we pass state as props in functional component using navigationOptions in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm a newbie in React Native and I want to ask how can we pass a hook state in functional component to another screen, using navigationOptions

Here's the code:

```
const Screen = props => {
const [eventName, setEventName] = useState('');

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    props.navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (

        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
          <Item 
            title="Finish"
            iconName={Platform.OS === 'adroid' ? 'done-all' : 'done-all'}
            onPress={() => {
              props.navigation.navigate('TripsListDetailScreen', {
                final_eventName: eventName,

              })
            }}
          />
      </HeaderButtons>
    )
    });
  }, [props.navigation]);

return(...);
}
```

I'm trying to pass the `eventName` to the other screen. Since we have to style the `headerRight` using `navigationOptions` outside the component like:

```
Screen.navigationOptions = data => {
    return(
        headerTitle:...,
        headerRight: ....

)
}
```

we can't pass the params there. So I tried the `React.useLayoutEffect()` as described in [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons)

But the screen throws an error:

[image: Error]

Please help

Comment: Most probably `props.navigation.setOptions` is `undefined`. Can you please check what it is logging for `console.log(props.navigation)`?

Comment: It logs just like usual :|

{"actions": {"dismiss": [Function dismiss], "goBack": [Function goBack], "navigate": [Function navigate], "pop": [Function pop], "popToTop": [Function popToTop], "push": ..... 

Sorry for the limits of words, I cant give you more :(

Comment: btw, I'm using v.4. The docs v4 doesn't talk about how to do that with functional component. So I use the v5 guides

Comment: Oh It doesn't have ```setOptions``` function. Is that the problem ?

Comment: Yes, because you are trying to call it as a function like `props.navigation.setOptions({ })`. With `undefined` value for `setOptions` it's not possible.

Comment: So do you know how can we fix this ?

Comment: Unfortunately not but that's definitely an issue, that function has to be there is you want to call that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know where the problem is now. When I log the `props.navigation` it doesn't have the `setOptions` function.
Moreover, when I look back the doc, I found out it's the because of the version I'm using.

I'm using reac-navigation v4 but the `props.navigation.setOptions` is only available in v5.

What a pity :(

Thanks @norbitrial for pointing that out for me

If you have any answer regardless of the problem of the version issue, I'd be very happy to know !